# ng-selected does not work with ng-repeat to set default value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to set default value of options 
I am using select and ng-repeat. I do get data in js file and I do call model to set value there.

Please have a look for below code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngrepeat-select-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select  ng-model="datamodel">
      <option ng-repeat="dataitem in data"
                ng-selected ="{{dataitem == datamodel}}">{{dataitem}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{datamodel}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $scope.datamodel = 2;
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ccFbzImRMbn8T1LHlDys?p=preview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

> Note that the value of a select directive used without ngOptions is
>   always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string
>   value, you must either explicitly convert it using a directive (see
>   example below) or use ngOptions to specify the set of options. This is
>   because an option element can only be bound to string values at
>   present.

So changing `$scope.datamodel = 2;` to `$scope.datamodel = '2';` works. See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ooPp9dJnwjVP9n6T75yD?p=preview).

However, it's better to use `ngOptions` instead. Again, from the docs:

> In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on `<option>` elements instead of
>   ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides
>   some benefits, such as more flexibility in how the `<select>`'s model is
>   assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression, and
>   additionally in reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a
>   new scope for each repeated instance.

So to keep your model as an integer, you can rather use:

```
<select  ng-model="datamodel" ng-options="dataitem for dataitem in data">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3b2HARMOc6Yiy7kfJFO0?p=preview)

Comment: It works ! Awesome ! I just convert integer into string and all set.

Comment: I am trying to set max number as default value but not from .js file so that's I am using ng-repeat.  here is Link : (http://plnkr.co/edit/zJbQTVPaErP2dKe5gUXv?p=preview)

Comment: @FShah think you can still use `ng-options`, can you fork your plunker to show what you mean? You could possibly use `ng-init` to set your model value to the last element in the list if the list is sorted from min to max

Comment: @FShah is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/GGrtQMJJJK7H1CwVlAC6?p=preview) what you're looking for? It only works on the assumption that your `data` list is ordered

Comment: Perfect - This is exactly I was looking for , Great