# Cannot select default value in dropdown using ng-model and ng-repeat or ng-select in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm really new to AngularJS and i like it very much.
But i'm experiencing a problem trying to initialize a prealoaded dropdown with a specific value.

The dropdown is initialized with values available from JSON array, but when i try to select a default value in this dropdown, i don't see that value selected but the ng-model variable is set correctly.

I created a plunker example here http://plnkr.co/edit/7su3Etr1JNYEz324CMy7?p=preview tryng to achieve what i want, but i can't get it to work. I tried with ng-repeat and ng-select, with no luck. Another try i did (in this example) is trying to set the ng-selected property.

This is a part of my html

```
<body ng-controller="MySampleController">
  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="SelectedStatus" ng-init="SelectedStatus">
    <option ng-repeat="option in StatusList[0]" value="{{option.key}}" ng-selected="{{option.key==SelectedStatus}}">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="SelectedOrigin">
    <option ng-repeat="option in OriginList[0]" value="{{option.key}}" ng-selected="{{option.key == SelectedOrigin}}">{{option.key}} - {{option.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <pre>Selected Value For Status: {{SelectedStatus}}</pre>
  <pre>{{StatusList[0]}}</pre>
  <pre>Selected Value For Origin: {{SelectedOrigin}}</pre>
  <pre>{{OriginList[0]}}</pre>
</body>
```

And this is code from my controller

```
function MySampleController($scope) {

        $scope.StatusList = [];
    $scope.OriginList = [];    
    $scope.ServiceCall = {};
    $scope.EntityList = [];

    $scope.SelectedStatus = -3;
    $scope.SelectedOrigin = 1;

        var myList = [
            {
                item: 'Status',
                values: [{ key: -3, name: 'Aperto' },
                         { key: -1, name: 'Chiuso' }]
            },
            {
                item: 'Origin',
                values: [{ key: 1, name: 'Origin1' },
                            { key: 2, name: 'Origin2' },
                            { key: 3, name: 'Origin3' }]
            }
        ];

      $scope.documentsData = myList;
      angular.forEach($scope.documentsData, function (value) {
            $scope.EntityList.push(value);
            switch ($scope.EntityList[0].item) {
                case 'Status':
                    $scope.StatusList.push($scope.EntityList[0].values);                    
                    $scope.EntityList = [];
                    break;
                case 'Origin':
                    $scope.OriginList.push($scope.EntityList[0].values);
                    $scope.EntityList = [];
                    break;
            }

        });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat + option`, in which case the default value works just fine.

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect"
        ng-options="opt.key as opt.key+'-'+opt.name for opt in StatusList[0]"
        ng-model="SelectedStatus"></select>`
```

You can also make it a bit more readable by specifying the option label as a scope function.

HTML: `ng-options="opt.key as getOptionLabel(opt) for opt in StatusList[0]"`

Controller:

```
$scope.getOptionLabel = function(option) {
  return option.key + " - " + option.name;
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7BcAuzX5JV7lCQh772oo?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the answer Fissio, i already tried with ng-options, but maybe my array of values was malformed, so i can't get it to work. I will do another try because i get values from web services that gives me back integer values, so better if i can make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Value of a select directive used without ngOptions is always a string.

Set as following and it would work

```
$scope.SelectedStatus = '-3';
$scope.SelectedOrigin = '1';
```

Read answer here in details [ng-selected does not work with ng-repeat to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303991/ng-selected-does-not-work-with-ng-repeat-to-set-default-value)

Comment: Thanks Amit, just after i posted my question i made some other try and got it to work exactly as you sayid.
Thank you anyway! :)